# Disable automatic line numbering for ECCV2014 conference template

Tags: formatting, line-numbering

I'm writing a study report with [ECCV2014 conference template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/532b5bb12608a9f06580ffe3), as the following image shows, this template automatically generates line numbering and I want to disable it so I can write some comments on the side.

[image: Auto line numbering of ECCV 2014 conference paper]

I've scan through the llncs.cls file and searched for something like "linenumber", "numberline","contectline" and comment any sentences containing these words, but it still won't work. Could someone give me some help？ Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: remove or comment `\usepackage{ruler}` in your `.tex` file

Comment: Wow that works lol, much appreciated bro

Comment: Use \nolinenumbers